# After turning a list into string I cannot get [0]

Tags: python

I read a text file in python as:

```
anagram = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as text_file:
    for lines in text_file:
        anagram.append(lines.strip().split(','))
print (anagram)
```

where it prints:

```
[['pot', 'top'], ['room', ' door'], ['wink', ' true']]
```

when I ask for the type it says class list. So I run the following code to convert it into string:

```
alist = str(anagram[0])
```

however, when I run the following code:

```
print (alist[0])
```

I get the following result:

```
[
```

instead, I want to get the word pot.

How can I do that?

Comment: if you want to get output as 'pot', then you should write `print(anagram[0][0])`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the string casting altogether. It turns the list to it's string representation, "['pot', 'top']". It's first character is indeed '['.

This will print what you're looking for:

```
alist = anagram[0]
print(alist[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

If we run these lines in a terminal:

```
>>> anagram = [['pot', 'top'], ['room', ' door'], ['wink', ' true']]
>>> alist = str(anagram[0])
>>> alist
"['pot', 'top']"
>>> alist[0]
'['
```

You can see that the line `alist = str(anagram[0])` is converting the first `list` in `anagram` into a `string`. Then `alist[0]` is getting the first character from that string: `[`.

Just remove the `str` and you will get the list:

```
alist = anagram[0]
```